# Axios requests not run fully asynchronously. TTFB increasing with each request?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a couple of similar Vue.js components on a page, each of which needs to send an API request to my server using axios.

The requests look like this:

```
this.axios.get(`/api/stock/${this.sku}`)
  .then(result => {
    this.stockLevel = result.data
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

The resulting requests look like this in the Chrome Dev Tools:

[image: Chrome Dev tools]

As you can see, the requests are *started* at the same time, but the TTFB increases with each request.

It seems as if the requests are not run fully asynchronously. If possible, I would much rather have the requests not block each other the way they are right now.

Do you have any idea on what is happening here and how to prevent it?

The backend is running on a simple Nginx server using HTTP2, and according the server logs, the requests are actually received *after* one another (and not at the same time).

You help is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: async does not mean that all requests will be sent the same time. 
By 'the requests are actually received after one another` you mean after sending response or after receiving request? It will be always the way that request coming one after another as they will never come the same time..

Comment: I guess I expected my application to send multiple requests, without having to wait for prior requests to finish. By 'the requests are actually received after on another' I just meant that the bottleneck seems to be in the frontend: The server receives the requests with about 0.04s in between them.

Comment: without having your actual frontend and / or backend code it's hard to tell where the bottleneck is. If you do a lot of stuff between your different requests 0.04s could be a valid time between. Maybe your backend can't handle the different requests at the same time? Blocked resources?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed bad perf with axios on a vuejs project too. TTFB was around 450ms when in concurrence with other browser requests (Chrome).

I switch to `fetch` and TTFB is now down to ~10ms on that same page.

**`/!\`** the [`fetch api`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is not yet [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch) by IE11 (september 2017) **`/!\`**

Your code would then be:

`` var vm = this
fetch(`/api/stock/${this.sku}`)
  .then(result => {
      result.json().then(data => {vm.stockLevel = data})
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  }) ``